# Meaning of "Collects information"

Tags: android, google-play-console

In

> App Content > Target audience and content

of Play Console if we select for example range age of "9-12" age this text is displayed

> If you collect personally identifiable information of minors, it can
>   be removed from Google Play (text translated by me from other ln)

What is meaning of collect?

If I get some info of user and send to my server, It is clear that it is to collect. If I save information (in variables) with the sole purpose of showing it to the user on the screen, is it to collect?

My case: my app is a file explorer and it show to user files, images, audio, apps from device. Is this, collect?, so a file explorer can´t have target audience < 13 years?

I have tried to ask Google, but their response has been a generic email without information. I have also read all the family police and I have not had an answer.

**Note**, if you vote down, please thank you for saying what the problem is so I won't repeat it again.

Comment: Bro I can't clearly understand google policies but maybe you are trying to add below 13 you have to submit a children policies.

Comment: Text not say that I need a policy, say "If you collect personally identifiable information of minors, it can be removed from Google Play". I ask in this question what means "collects information".

Comment: What is your app type(category)?

Comment: Tools, is a file explorer.

Comment: try with personal

Comment: No, all file browsers are in tools. In addition, the category does not influence the policies you have to comply with.

Comment: it is preventing you because of tools because if I am right so the limitation of tools is above 13 years.

Comment: Can you add a link that has the source or more info of what you said?

Comment: sorry bro, I forget the where I read.